# How do I make one or multiple objects follow another object?

Tags: java, object

For the final project of my CS class I'm trying to make a zombies game, where a survivor is being followed by a number of zombies. I'm still on early stages but there is one thing that I'm still struggling with. To make the zombie follow the player, I made is that the X and the Y of the zombies change by a 10th of towards the X and Y of the player. However, there are two problems with the code. Firstly, the zombie stops following the player when it gets too close and never actually reaches the player even when standing still. Secondly, the zombie will go nonstop in the initial direction of the player after moving and does not stop when it reaches it and then exists the fields. I tried using if statements to keep the zombie in the screen and following the player but failed.

Here is the code:

These are the codes in the class that belongs to the zombie object

This is how I get the direction for the zombie

```
public void getDirection(int px , int py)
    {

        dx =(px - getX())/50;
        dy =(py - getY())/50;

    }
public void act() 
{
```

And this is how I move the zombie

```
    //moveX(player.getX());
    //moveY(player.getY());
    if((getX()<player.getX()) && (getX() < player.getY()))
    {
        setX(getX()+dx);
        setY(getY()+dy);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your best attempt with `if`s.  Make sure to provide proper comments.

Answer (score 0):

Consider giving zombies a constant speed, so they don't slow down when close. Use the deltas to determine direction but not speed.

Consider marking a hit when a zombie is *close enough* to the player, that is, when `abs(player.x - zombie.x) < close_enough and abs(player.y - zombie.y) < close_enough`. This makes sense if your figures are larger than the grid size of your play field, then `close_enough` would be half the width of the zombie sprite.

In that case, the zombie speed should be less than the width of the sprite, else a zombie and a player will be able to 'jump' one another without meeting on a collision course.